# Error while trying to installing the metaSeq package on R 3.6.3

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

I am trying to install the `metaSeq` package using this code:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("metaseqR")
```

But I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in packageVersion("BiocManager") : 
  there is no package called ‘BiocManager’
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
```

Before running your code.